# Scrollspy horizontal position is incorrect

Tags: bootstrap-4, scrollspy

I am using Bootstrap 4 and have created a navbar with Scrollspy.  When I click on any navbar link, it overshoots the correct horizontal location.  I have tried using data-offset but nothing changes. Other than this, it is working properly.  I've searched for a solution unsuccessfully.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" style="position: relative">
<!-- -------------------NAVBAR--------------------- -->

<nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark" >
  <div class="container">  
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#" >Logo???</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#els">Event Listeners</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#rcs">Random Color Selectors</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Color Theories</a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#rgb">RGB</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#hsb">HSB</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#hex">HEX</a>
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#muns">Munsell</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#cspec">Color Spectrum</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#contact">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul> 
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```html
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navbar" data-offset="50">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm bg-dark navbar-dark fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Logo???</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar" id="navbarNav">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav_item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#home">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav_item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#els">Event Listeners</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav_item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#rcs">Random Color Selectors</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown">
                        Section 4
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section41">Link 1</a>
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#section42">Link 2</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="home" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
            <h2> HOME:What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="els" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
            <h2>ELS: What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col" id="rcs" style="padding-top:70px;padding-bottom:70px">
            <h2>rcs:: What is Lorem Ipsum?</h2>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
            <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the
                industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
                scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap
                into
                electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the
                release of
                Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like
                Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
```